# Select element in linq and change properties

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have two lists objects with this classes

```
class Sku 
{
   public string skuId { get; set; }
   public int qty { get; set; }
   public string city { get; set; }
}

 class SkuWithCity
 {
    public string skuId { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
```

And I have two lists with objects:

```
List<Sku> skuList = new List<Sku>();
List<SkuWithCity> skuListWithCity = List<SkuWithCity>();
```

Imagine that in the first list(skuList), the property "City" of each object is null.

What I want to do is, using linq, select the sku objects that have the same skuId and add the city. Somethis like:

```
var result = from skuElements in skuList
               from skuWCity in skuListWithCity 
               where skuElements.sku == skuWCity.sku
               select skuElements 
               {
                   skuElements.city = skuWCity.city,  
               };
```

**And get the whole object, not just the city**

int order to get:

|Object  | Qty   |  City
|----    |----|
|AAA   |     2 |    Panama|

|BBB   |     5   | Rio De Janeiro|

is this even possible, get the whole object and modify one or many properties?

**UPDATE:** In real life the object that I'm trying to copy has a lot of members, that is why I'm trying to "copy" de object of list A and just modify some attributes using the match object of list B.

Comment: You can use Linq to get the matching items then iterate over them to do the update.  You shouldn't try to mutate items in Linq.

Comment: are you looking for a union of both tables or do you just want one row return per unique skuId in the form of Id/Qty/Name? Also why would you have two tables that are basically the same? Also add the city where in table SKU?

Comment: I want to "complete" the info using the two lists. I have two tables because the info comes from two different sources. Maybe a join would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to update the existing objects instead of projecting to a new set of objects then first use a join to get the matching items.

```
var result = from skuElement in skuList
             join skuWCity in skuListWithCity
             on skuElements.skuId == skuWCity.skuId
             select skuElements 
             {
                 skuElement,
                 skuWCity
             };
```

Then iterate them and do the update.

```
foreach(var x in result)
{
    x.skuElement.City = x.skuWCity.City;
}
```

Note this does not handle the case where more than one item in either list has more than one match in the other.  I'm assuming that the lists have a one-to-one match already.

Alternatively you could just use a dictionary.

```
var cities = skuListWithCity.ToDictionary(s => s.skuId, s => s.City);
foreach(var s in skuList)
{
    s.City = cities[s.skuId];
}
```

Note that this fails if there are duplicate `skuId` in `skuListWithCity` or if a `skuId` in `skuList` is not in `skuListWithCity`

Comment: True, but since this is not a natural LINQ operation, why bother with LINQ at all (joins and anonymous projection) while simple `Dictionary` would do the same with less code.

Comment: @IvanStoev Mainly trying to show that you don't do mutations in the Linq code, but you are correct.

Comment: Which was good of course, since the OP code and another answer are just defining something which never executes :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `join` and then make a *projection* of the result set as below:

```
var result = from skuElements in skuList
             join skuWCity in skuListWithCity
             on skuElements.skuId equals skuWCity.skuId 
             select new Sku 
             {
                 skuId = skuElements.skuId, 
                 qty = skuElements.qty,
                 city = skuWCity.city,  
             };
```

Comment: I never heard the term projection used  before, more you're creating an anonymous type.

Comment: @Edward it's a common term used in LINQ. *The process of choosing what parts of an object to select is called projection and the result of that operation is a projection*. For further info, please have a look at http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/Linq/Lesson02. Furthremore, the object in which we project each result row of the result set is of a specific type, it's not anonymous.

Comment: @Edward That's not an anonymous type. `new Sku`

Comment: @juharr you're right I only glanced and saw the "new"

Comment: @Christos I doubt the authority of the site you used as reference, being it is loaded with tons of ads.

Comment: @Edward If you google it as a term, you will find many links through which you can verify that projection is a term that is used in LINQ. One more link, that's from the personal blog of Jon Skeet...https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-3-quot-select-quot-and-a-rename/, *Again, they both operate the same way – but the second overload allows the index into the sequence to be used as part of the **projection**.....*

Comment: @Christos Thanks for the second link I definitely recognized [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s name from SO.